# Alternating series inequalities

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

> For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we define:
>   $$x_{n}=\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4!}+...+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}$$

I want to show that $\forall\space m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m\ge n$:

$$|x_{m}-x_{n}|<\frac{1}{nn!}$$

I managed to show $$|x_{m}-x_{n}|\le \frac{1}{(n+1)!}+...+\frac{1}{m!}$$ but don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Rather show that $$|x_{m}-x_{n}|\le \frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\frac{1}{(n+3)!}-\frac{1}{(n+4)!}+\cdots+(-1)^{m+n}\frac{1}{m!}$$ and proceed from there.

Comment: How do you get that? Doesn't the triangular inequality eliminate all negative signs?

Comment: Precisely, one must be cleverer than the triangle inequality here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$$ 
 a_1 \ge a_2 \ge a_3 \ge a_4 \ge \ldots \ge a_N \ge 0
$$
are decreasing, non-negative real numbers then the alternating sum
$$
 S = a_1 - a_2 + a_3 - a_4 + \ldots \pm a_N  \\
$$
satisfies
$$
 a_1 - a_2 \le S \le a_1 \, ,
$$
as can be seen by grouping pairs of consecutive terms in two
possible ways:
$$
\begin{aligned}
  S &= a_1 - a_2 + (a_3 - a_4) + (a_5 - a_6) + \ldots \quad \ge a_1 - a_2 \, ,\\
  S &= a_1 - (a_2 - a_3) - (a_4 - a_5) - \ldots \quad \le a_1 \, .
\end{aligned}
$$

Applying this to
$$
 (-1)^n (x_m - x_n) =  \frac{1}{(n+1)!} - \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \ldots
 \pm \frac{1}{m!} 
$$
gives
$$
 \frac{1}{(n+1)!} - \frac{1}{(n+2)!} \le |x_m-x_n|\le \frac{1}{(n+1)!}<\frac{1}{nn!} \, .
$$